# How can I speed up my openpyxl program reading Excel .xlsx files?

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Like many folks I need to read both .xls files (I call them S files, using xlrd) and .xlsx files (the X files, using openpyxl), in both cases files of about 30,000 rows.  And in both cases I'm just copying all excel data read out to a .csv file, no other processing so just Input/Output.

But the X file operations are over 200 times slower than for .xls, for example reading a 30,000 row .xlsx file now takes 2 minutes compared to 1/2 second for .xls with xlrd.   We have thousands of files to process so the time per file matters.

Is openpyxl that much slower or do I need to do something, like release some resource at the end of each row?

BTW, I have made several great improvements by using read_only=True and reading a row at a time instead of cell by cell 
as shown in the following code segment.  Thanks to blog.davep.org 
    https://blog.davep.org/2018/06/02/a_little_speed_issue_with_openpyxl.html

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("excel_file.xlsx",  data_only=True,  read_only=True)
    sheet = wb.active
    for row in sheet.rows:
        for cell in row:
            cell_from_excel = cell.value
```